# Kafka JsonDeserializer with support for multiple date formats

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

i am learning kafka and i am struggling with custom implementation of a JsonDeserializer for consumer where my object has a Date field which should accept multiple formats.

For example i want it to be possible to parse from producer a message with date = "2021/09/12" or "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM" or even a long timestamp 1231231321.

If it was only one field i could just write my custom deserializer class, but because i have an object with multiple type fields , how can i include my custom date deserializer? Do i just have a generic JsonDeserializer and on my object annotate?

```
@JsonFormat(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom deserializer like this,

```
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        String dateString = jsonparser.getText();
        return parse(dateString);
    }

    private Date parse(String dateString) {
        final String[] formats = {
                "M/d/y H:m",
                "y/M/d"};
        
        // Used to check the epoch timestamp
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{10}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dateString);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return new Date(Long.parseLong(dateString) * 1000); // here assumed `dateString` in seconds.
        }

        for (String format : formats) {
            try { return new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(dateString); }
            catch (ParseException e) {/* do nothing */}
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or you can do something like this as well.

*Note: Only difference is `parse` method*

```
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        String dateString = jsonparser.getText();
        return parse(dateString);
    }

    private Date parse(String dateString) {
        final Map<String, String> patterns  = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("M/d/y H:m", "^\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}$");
            put("y/M/d", "^\\d{4}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}$");
        }};

        // Used to check the epoch timestamp
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{10}");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(dateString);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return new Date(Long.parseLong(dateString) * 1000); // here assumed `dateString` in seconds.
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pattern : patterns.entrySet()) {
            if (matcher.usePattern(Pattern.compile(pattern.getValue())).matches()) {
                try { return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern.getKey()).parse(dateString); }
                catch (ParseException e) {/* do nothing */} }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

*Note: My suggestion is to use second method.*

Then you need to tell Jackson to use this deserializer when deserializing to `Date` class. You can do this by two ways.

You annotate every `Date` parameter in your class like this,

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
private Date dateParam;
```

Or you can register this deserializer against `Date` class like this,

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        builder.failOnEmptyBeans(false)
                .deserializerByType(Date.class, new CustomDateDeserializer());
    }
}
```